# Algorithm for packing various shapes inside of a rectangle

Tags: algorithms, mathematical-programming, packing

Say I am given a rectangle of width $W$ and length $L$. I now have to fit as many regular shapes of area $A$ into this rectangle as possible. For example, if the shape is a circle, I need to fit as many circles of area $A$ into the rectangle as possible. All the shapes trying to be packed in a given instance are identical, we also assume we are living in 2D.

What would be the general way to approach this problem? Can it be done with a program or is this a mathematical question?

Comment: Perhaps looking into [Packing Problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems) might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by the other answer, this is an example of [bin packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem), a type of problem that is [NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness).

[Skiena](http://www.springer.com/gb/book/9781848000698) Section 17.9 reports:

> Fortunately, relatively simple heuristics tend to work well on most
>   bin-packing problems.

The same source provides the following heuristic recommendation:

> Analytical and empirical results suggest that *first-fit decreasing* is
>   the best heuristic. Sort the objects in decreasing order of size, so
>   that the biggest object is first and the smallest last. Insert each
>   object one by one into the first bin that has room for it. If no bin
>   has room, we must start another bin. In the case of one-dimensional
>   bin packing, this can never require more than $22\%$ more bins than
>   necessary and usually does much better. First-fit decreasing has an
>   intuitive appeal to it, for we pack the bulky objects first and hope
>   that little objects can fill up the cracks.
>
> First-fit decreasing is easily implemented in $O(n \ \text{lg} n + bn)$
>   time, where $b \leq min(n,m)$ is the number of bins actually used.
>   Simply do a linear sweep through the bins on each insertion. A faster
>   $O(n \ \text{lg} n)$ implementation is possible by using a binary tree
>   to keep track of the space remaining in each bin. We can fiddle with
>   the insertion order in such a scheme to deal with problem-specific
>   constraints.

I recommend reading the original material in its entirety.

Answer (score 1):

The problem for shapes of general form is in the class of [NP-Hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard), so there is nos efficient algorithm to solve this problem. [Bin packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) is a well known class of problems.

The approach will depend on your intentions:

- Need a complete algorithm, i.e. an algorithm that compute the correct solution for the problem but can only compute small instances of your problem.
- Need a fast approximation algorithm, i.e an algorithm that compute a "good" solution for large instances but not necessarily the optimal. I have seen very nice results using meta heuristics to solve this.

Almost every code I have seen so far works with not any kind of shapes but small sub classes such as polygons and circles.

Comment: A good approximation would definitely be good. What is the algorithm?